# Right align text in Bulma panel-block

Tags: bulma

How can I right align text in a `panel-block`? I've attempted using `is-pulled-right` on the span I wanted moved to right in this example:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.2/css/bulma.min.css" integrity="sha256-qS+snwBgqr+iFVpBB58C9UCxKFhyL03YHpZfdNUhSEw=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="panel">
        <a class="panel-block">
            <span>Foo</span>
            <span class="is-pulled-right">Bar</span>
        </a>
    </nav>
</body>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kevinastock/pen/mdeXbBw)

I would like "Bar" moved to the right side of the `panel-block`. I've also attempted using a `level` with the contents of body as such:

```html
    <nav class="panel">
        <a class="panel-block">
            <div class="level">
                <div class="level-left">
                    <span class="level-item">Foo</span>
                </div>
                <div class="level-right">
                    <span class="level-item">Bar</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </nav>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kevinastock/pen/zYvROWY)

but this does not change how it displays.

Answer (score 3):

I was pulling my hair out. @mitchell-long 's answer was the saving grace. I think the `is-block` argument in the class is what did it.

I was able to use levels too if anyone is interested.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mrmulla/pen/jOLRrKz)

```
<a class="panel-block is-block" href="#">
  <nav class="level">
   <!-- Left side -->
   <div class="level-left">
    <p class="level-item">
      Foo
    </p>
    </div>
    <!-- Right side -->
    <div class="level-right">
      <p class="level-item">
         Bar
     </p>
    </div>
   </nav>
 </a>
```

Comment: This did absolutely what I wanted! Adding `is-block` to the `panel-block` I was then able to use a level as its child with `level-left` and `level-right` to have text at one end and control buttons at the other

Answer (score 1):

I might try using the Bulma [Columns](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/).

This should work:

```
<nav class="panel">
  <a class="panel-block is-block">
    <div class="columns">
      <span class="column">foo</span>
      <span class="column has-text-right">bar</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="panel">
 <div class="panel-block is-justify-content-space-between">
  <p class="is-pulled-left">Foo</div>
  <p class="is-pulled-right">Bar</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

`is-justify-content-space-between` is what you need as per the [docs](https://bulma.io/documentation/helpers/flexbox-helpers/)